# SQL Server Full traceability of a product

Tags: sql-server, recursion, traceability

I'm creating a program that manages a manufacturing plant, and I need to show each product's traceability (all the paths it took from creation until it's final delivery.
Let me show you an example:
The plant creates the document `A001`, with quantity `400`.
Then, they need to split the product, creating documents `B002` and `B003`, both with quantity `200` and both with their `Parent` field value of `A001`.
After that, they'll split `B002` into smaller pieces. That creates documents `C004`, `C005`, `C006` and `C007`, all with quantity `50` and all with the `Parent` field value `B002`.These smaller pieces can also be split again...

Now, if I wanted to trace the full cycle of document `B002`, I'd check the `Parent` field and cross it with the document field to get that info, and then get the documents where the `Parent` field is `B002`. That's the "easy" part.

Now the tricky part.

I want to know the full cycle of document `C007`. I'd have to check his parent, and get the `B002` document, THEN have to get that document's `Parent` and get the `A001` document. I'd also check for documents with `Parent` `C007` and find none.

Or know the full cycle of document `A001`. I'd check if there was any `Parent` (there won't be), they i'd have to get all the documents with `Parent` `A001`, then get all documents with `Parent` `B002` and `B003` and so on.

Is there any function on SQL that let's me do this, or do I have to create a procedure that recurs itself over and over to check for both parents and childs? And if so, I have no idea what to do, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you ask for something simple that has been done thousands of times - find the root of a tree.

There are various approaches to that, among other things a special data type (HierarchyId) that supports that right in SQL Server.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx

is the documentation for this.

That said, you likely will use a normal field as ID - and then the best approach is a stored procedure.

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/hierarchies_in_sql_server_databases.htm

has some thoughts about it - as has google tons of it (there are various approaches to query them).

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

is from quite a reputable source and using a CTE Like this:

```
WITH MyCTE
AS ( SELECT EmpID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerID
FROM Employee
WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT EmpID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerID
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN MyCTE ON Employee.ManagerID = MyCTE.EmpID
WHERE Employee.ManagerID IS NOT NULL )
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
```